# Are daily quests in Heroes of the Storm the same for everyone?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Are the new Daily quests in Heroes of the Storm the same for all players?

Assuming that there 3 empty places for quests, will all players get the same 3 quests for 3 days?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Daily quests are **not** the same for everyone. The reason you might suspect this is the case is because there aren't many possible quests to get.

List of possible daily quests:

- Play 8 Games (Any Mode) - 800 gold
- Win 3 Games (Any Mode) - 600 gold
- Play 3 Games as an Assassin Hero - 300 gold
- Play 3 Games as a Warrior Hero - 300 gold
- Play 3 Games as a Support Hero - 300 gold
- Play 3 Games as a Specialist Hero - 300 gold
- Play 2 Games As a Warcraft Hero - 200 gold
- Play 2 Games As a Diablo Hero - 200 gold
- Play 2 Games As a StarCraft Hero - 200 gold

If the reason you are asking this is because you seem to get a lot of supports in your team on a day when you got a quest 'play as a support' you should also know that matchmaking system has some rules in group creation.

For further information, check the official site [here.](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/15145471/matchmaking-design-in-heroes-of-the-storm-8-8-2014)